# Typescript error adding hintText to a TextField in create-react-app-with-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Having just downloaded, installed and run the create-react-app-with-typescript, I have been experimenting with various components. When I added a TextField with hintText using the following lines:

`import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';`

and

```
  <TextField hintText="Hint Text"/><br />
  <Typography variant="display1" gutterBottom>
    Material-UI
  </Typography>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
(56,20): Type '{ hintText: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

material-ui version is 1.0.0-beta.38.
typescript version is 2.7.2.

I tried including @types/material-ui, but that created a host of other problems (which, based on reading other posts is expected with this version of material-ui).

Ideas?

Update: One thing I just noticed is that if I view the docs by running npm start in the docs directory after cloning the repo, the examples are somewhat different than what I found here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new version of Material-UI where the `hintText` prop has been replace by `placeholder`. You should be able to use:

```
<TextField placeholder="something" />
```

See her for more examples: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/

Comment: Yes, thank you. Those examples are the ones I was seeing when I ran the doc locally.

Comment: If you cloned the material-ui repo, you'll need to switch branches to v1-beta for the new version.